# Deleted ".git" folder manually but still its reflecting as a Working directory

Tags: git, bash

I want to uninitialized the working `git` directory so I manually deleted the `.git` folder. But still if I go to my Project folder through `git bash` It's reflects as [image]  `Eclipse`(My Project)as a Master and see in the list there is no `.git` folder present.

If I do git Status then it shows this [image]

Comment: "go to my Project folder through git bash" --- what is "git bash"?

Comment: git bash is the command line interface that you can opt-in to install when you install git on windows. It's basically a glorified cygwin shell.

Comment: @Devraj that screenshot really doesn't say much, it is just a directory listing without a `.git` folder. I am willing to bet running `git status` there will tell you that you are not in a git repo.

Comment: @ivarni I have added the git status Screen shot. It says that its still a working directory. Why?

Comment: You need move your directory out of the working tree that is the parent directory, too.

Comment: @CharlesBailey I'm sorry, but why would i do this?. I usually just delete that .git folder and I can uninitialized the working directory.

Comment: I thought you wanted this directory to not be under Git control. While it's in a Git working tree, it will be under Git control. Perhaps you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @CharlesBailey What I am looking for is to uninitialized a git working directory. My way is to remove the .git folder and its done. If you know another way around please suggest. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a `.git` folder in `~/workspace`?

Comment: @Devraj: That is a valid way, so you can remove the `.git` directory from the parent directory as well although this means that all of `~/workspace` will not longer be a Git working tree. Is that what you want?

Comment: @ivarni no there is no .git folder in workspace.

Comment: @Devraj: did you look at my answer? That is the way to know where the git configuration files are.

Comment: @Peque , Yes i did and I am amazed by one thing that i have one .git folder in my "Workspace" earlier it wasn't there. Now what i did: 
First :-I've deleted .git folder of "workspace". Now there is no working directory.( not eclipse neither Workspace)
Second:-I am stuck again in a scenario ,When I do git init in "workspace" then "Workspace" and "Eclipse" become working directory. Do you know the reason why?

Comment: @Devraj: of course you had one. Anyway, if your question is answered, you should mark it as solved. If you have other questions/problems, then open a new one. Take into account that Git will always by default track all files under the top-level directory; if you want to ignore a particular folder, use the `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` for git configuration files. Or even better, what is the output of `git rev-parse --git-dir`?

What `git rev-parse --git-dir` does is to show where the git configuration directory is, which I think is what he wants to know. That command will probably point to a parent directory of course.